# C++ template method forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I'm having a little problem with my classes. I have two classes which both use template methods, therefore I have to put it in the header. Here is an example. I'd like it to compile properly without the "forward declaration incomplete" problem. I understand what is wrong but I can't figure how to correct this. Thank you guys.

class.h

```
    class A;
    class B;

    class A
    {
        B *foo;

        template <class T>
        void func()
        {
            foo->fanc();   
        }
    }

    class B
    {
       A *foo;

       void fanc();

       template <class T>
       void osef()
       {
            foo->func<int>();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependence. You can not declare an object of incomplete class. You can solve this by declaring either pointers or references to the incomplete class.

```
class A
{
    B* foo;
```

or

```
class A
{
    B& foo;
```

On the later case you have to initialize the reference with the member initialization list of the constructor.

---

If you are using pointer then you should move the definition of the memeber function after the definition of the incomplte class.

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
    B* foo;
    template <class T>
    void func();
};

class B
{
  // ...
};

template <class T>
inline void A::func()
^^^^^^                   // If you need to include the header in more than one source file.
{
    foo->fanc();   
}
```

Comment: I'm using pointers, I just forgot to put that in the example. I just can't use the methods because of the incomplete declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of the keyword "inline". have a nice day.